# How to set date condition Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

A quick question for JS:
I keep getting the alert "Please set Date in order to continue" even if i choose a different date for the date value. How can I resolve this?

```
if(tdate = "1111-11-11") {
    window.alert("Please set Date in order to continue");
} else if (tdate = y+"-"+m+"-"+d){
    window.alert("We cannot do a same day delivery! Please choose a later date")
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a variable instead of having a condition in the `if` statement, the "equal to" operator in javascript is `==` and not `=`

Proper statement should be `if (condition)`

```
    if ( tdate == "1111-11-11") {
        window.alert("Please set Date in order to continue");
    } else if (tdate == y+"-"+m+"-"+d){
        window.alert("We cannot do a same day delivery! Please choose a later date");
    } else {
    }
```